# Analog of GeneratingFunction for Newton series

Tags: functions

GeneratingFunction gives the generating function for Maclauren series. I wonder if there a similar function for Newton series.

If

$$g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}f(k)$$

Then g(x) is

```
GeneratingFunction[f[k]/k!, k, x]
```

If

$$g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{x}k f(k)$$

then how to find g(x) in closed form in Mathematica?

Comment: @ybeltukov original question was not answered though…

Comment: @chris you should not ask the same question twice (or emphasize the difference between them). You can draw attention to your question by placing a bounty on it.

Comment: @ybeltukov sure.